# How to apply, remove and re-apply the bytebuddy transformation?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'm trying to `apply, remove and re-apply` the bytebuddy transformation via the javaagent as the following code. The remove is worked properly via the `ResettableClassFileTransformer::reset`, but the re-apply is no worked.

```java
// The target classes

public @interface ToString {
}

public interface Greetable {
    String say(final String name);
}

@ToString
public class Greeter implements Greetable {
     public String say(final String name) {
         return "Hello " + name;
     }
}
```

```java
//note the some transform is from the example
new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
  @Override
  public DynamicType.Builder transform(DynamicType.Builder builder,
                                       TypeDescription     typeDescription,
                                       ClassLoader         classloader,
                                       JavaModule          module) {
    return builder.method(named("say"))
                  .intercept(FixedValue.value("transformed");
  }
})
```

```java
// The transformation
public class MyProgram {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        ByteBuddyAgent.install();
        AgentBuilder bldr = new AgentBuilder.Default().
                                             with(AgentBuilder.Listener.
                                                      StreamWriting.
                                                      toSystemOut()).
                                             with(RedefinitionStrategy.
                                                     RETRANSFORMATION).
                                             disableClassFormatChanges().
                                             type(isSubTypeOf(
                                                       Greetable.class)).
                                             transform(<some transform>);
        ResettableClassFileTransformer resetter = 
                                          bldr.installOnByteBuddyAgent();
        Greetable g1 = new Greeter();
        System.out.println(g1.say("001"));

        //remove the transformation
        resetter.reset(ByteBuddyAgent.getInstrumentation(),
                       RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION);
        Greetable g2 = new Greeter();
        System.out.println(g2.say("002"));

        //re-apply the transformation
        bldr.installOn(ByteBuddyAgent.getInstrumentation());
        Greetable g3 = new Greeter();
        System.out.println(g3.say("003"));

    }
}
```

The output is

```
TRANSFORM Greetable [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7ab2bfe1,
                     null,
                     loaded=true]
TRANSFORM Greeter [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7ab2bfe1,
                   null,
                   loaded=true]
transformed //note: the g1.say() is transformed.

Hello 002         //note: the g2 is an orginal

TRANSFORM Greetable [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7ab2bfe1,
                     null,
                     loaded=true]
TRANSFORM Greeter [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7ab2bfe1,
                   null,
                   loaded=true]
Hello 003         //note the re-apply has not worked.
```

Could you please help to advise how to achieve the re-apply?

#### EDIT1

I've updated the `byte-buddy` to version `1.6.11` and changed the `AgentBuilder.Transformer`. The result still same. The `g3.say()` is not transformed.

My environment is

```
Windows 10 64Bits

java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

#### EDIT2

I've changed the type matcher from interface

```java
type(isSubTypeOf(Greetable.class))
```

to concrete class as

```java
type(isSubTypeOf(Greeter.class))
```

The `g3.say()` is transformed propery. Is there any limitation on interface matching and transforming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running an old version of Byte Buddy as I can tell from the `AgentBuilder.Transformer` API. I just tried with a recent version and it works.

In practice, do you rely on the `@ToString` annotation for triggering the transformation? When you transform a class that is not yet loaded, Byte Buddy reads annotations from the class file directly. For a loaded class, it uses the loaded representation. Your annotation is not annotated with a `@RetentionPolicy(Retention.RUNTIME)` to retain the annotations visibility which might be the problem.

**UPDATE**: You need to refine your method matcher by excluding the `say` method from the interface by `not(isAbstract()).and(named("say"))`. Otherwise, you include the interface in your retransformation attempt. The JVM seems to silently fail the second retransformation because of this as you cannot change an abstract method into a default method after the class was loaded. Normally, this triggers a exception but in your case, the VM seems to silently suppress the error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I've updated the `byte-buddy` to version `1.6.11` as the updated question. Could you please help to advise further?

Comment: Next I've changed the `type matcher` from `interface` to `concrete class` and it works as the updated question #2. Is there any limitation?